# Useless Kotlin delegate

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, delegation

I'm trying to understand why we have feature as delegate in Kotlin.
This example is similar to wiki example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Check this commented fragment, I don't need it for using area function on bounds so why we should use  `: ClosedShape by bounds` ?

```
interface ClosedShape {
    fun area(): Int
}

class Rectangle(val width: Int, val height: Int) : ClosedShape {
    override fun area() = width * height
}

class Window(private val bounds: ClosedShape)  /*: ClosedShape by bounds */ {
    init {
        bounds.area()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> I don't need it for using area function on bounds

The point is *not* about whether you can use `area` on `bounds` or not. Sure, if all you want to do is to call `bounds.area()`, you don't need `: ClosedShape by bounds`.

Here's a little hypothetical situation, based on `ClosedShape` and `Window`, where using the `by` syntax to implement an interface is helpful.

Notice how a `Window` is `bound`ed by a `Rectangle`. Wouldn't it make sense for `Window` to also be a `ClosedShape`? If we have a function that works on `ClosedShape`, wouldn't it be nice if we can directly pass a `Window` to it, rather than passing `window.bounds`?

```
fun printArea(shape: ClosedShape) { 
    println(shape.area())
}

// we could write this:
printArea(window)

// rather than:
printArea(window.bounds)
```

This would mean that `Window` would implement `ClosedShape`. We *could* implement it without using a delegate:

```
class Window(private val bounds: ClosedShape) : ClosedShape {
    override fun area() = bounds.area()
}
```

But that would be very tedious if `ClosedShape` had many more methods than `area`. Imagine having to implement 20 methods, all of which just calls that same method on `bounds`:

```
class Window(private val bounds: ClosedShape) : ClosedShape {
    override fun area() = bounds.area()
    override fun perimeter() = bounds.perimeter()
    override fun numberOfSides() = bounds.numberOfSides()
    override fun isConcave() = bounds.isConcave()
    override fun contains(point: Point) = bounds.contains(point)
    override fun methodWithALotOfParameters(x: Int, y: String, z: Boolean) = bounds.methodWithALotOfParameters(x, y, z)
    override fun color() = bounds.color()
    // and so on...
}
```

You can also imagine how horrible this would get, if the delegate isn't as short as `bounds`, but something like `bounds.someProperty.anotherProperty`.

The `by` syntax eliminates all that tedious work, letting you just write:

```
class Window(private val bounds: ClosedShape) : ClosedShape by bounds
```

And that's it! You can now use any `Window` as a `ClosedShape`.